# Using $.get() to request large files and listening for completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to push the contents of a few large JSON files (i.e. at `"url1"` and `"url2"` and ~1MB size) to an array (i.e. `results`). I have tried using several variations of jQuery `$.get()` and `$.ajax()` but this either returns a fragment of the requested page or nothing at all even though xhttp was successful.

```
var urls = ["url1", "url2"];

function getData(urls) {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        $.get(urls[i], function(data) {
            results.push(data);
        });
    }
    var listen = setInterval(function() { // write results to console when done
        if (urls.length == results.length) {
            clearInterval(listen);
            console.log(results);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Is there a "proper" way I should be working with large files, or is something just fundamentally wrong with my approach?

Comment: You don't need your `listen` function, just add a `console.log()` directly to the `get` success callback function.

Comment: @ScottMarcus but I only want to continue with my pipeline (aka console.log() in this case) after all files are retrieved.

Comment: The callback function for the `get` will only run when the results are returned. It's already asynchronous. You can check the results array directly in the callback.

Comment: @ScottMarcus when all results in the 'for' loop have been returned?  Or just when each result specific to the url specified in the 'get' function have been returned?

Comment: If you specifically want to wait then you can set up a $.Deferred and resolve it when all files are retrieved

Comment: Right after your `results.push` line, you can add the same `if/then` test that you have in your `listen` to see if the newest results you just added have now caused all the results to be in.

Comment: @empiric yes this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "example.php", function() {
alert( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
 alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
 alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
  alert( "finished" );
});
```

Comment: How does that answer the question?